# XML exists() for deletion in tsql

Tags: xml, t-sql, xsd

When I try to delete an XML element that is not in the XML schema, I get

> Msg 2260, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
>   XQuery [Table_name.Table_XML_field.exist()]: There is no element named 'XML_element_name'

despite wrapping the delete in a boolean

```
IF EXISTS (select 'x'
from sys.xml_schema_collections xsc
    inner join sys.xml_schema_elements xse on xsc.xml_collection_id = xse.xml_collection_id
where 1 = 1
and xse.is_qualified = 0
and xsc.name = 'XML_schema_name'
and xse.name = 'XML_element_name')
BEGIN

UPDATE Table_name
SET Table_XML_field.modify(' delete (//XML_element_name)')
WHERE Table_XML_field.exist('(//XML_element_name)[1]') = 1

END
```

I wrap the deletion in a boolean condition, and still get that error.  Is there a different way to not execute the "UPDATE" statement if the XML node does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little horrible, but you can wrap your update in an EXEC():

```
IF EXISTS (...8<...)
BEGIN

EXEC('
UPDATE Table_name
SET Table_XML_field.modify('' delete (//XML_element_name)'')
WHERE Table_XML_field.exist(''(//XML_element_name)[1]'') = 1
')
END
```